# boost spirit parser look ahead parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, boost, boost-spirit

I want to parse a string which is of the form:
string_number.
I am not sure how to write a grammar for boost qi parser.

Right now my grammar looks like:

`+qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_-") >> lit('_') >> qi::int_`

But doesn't look like it works.
Example strings are:
ab_bcd_123 --> tokens(ab_bcd, 123)
ab_123 ---> tokens(ab, 123)

Answer (score 1):

> But doesn't look like it works.

That's because `0-9` eats the digits. This should work:

```
+qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> '_' >> qi::uint_
```

If you want to allow `ab-3_bcd_123` too, device a look-ahead to detect that you reached the end, e.g. `eoi`:

```
qi::raw[
    (+qi::alnum|'-') % (!('_' >> qi::uint_ >> eoi))
] >> '_' >> qi::uint_
```

allthough by now, I'd simply forget about it and do:

```
qi::lexeme [ +qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_-") ] [ _val = split_ident(_1) ];
```

See **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a53da73d81327a5d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using NumberedIdent = std::pair<std::string, int>;

namespace Demo {
    struct SplitIdent {
        NumberedIdent operator()(std::vector<char> const& v, bool& pass) const {
            std::string s(v.begin(), v.end());
            try {
                auto n = s.rfind('_');
                pass = n > 0;
                return { s.substr(0, n), std::stoi(s.substr(n+1)) };
            } catch(...) { 
                pass = false; return {s, 0}; 
            }
        }
    };

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    using namespace qi;

    static boost::phoenix::function<SplitIdent> split_ident;

    rule<It, NumberedIdent()> const rule
        = lexeme [ +char_("a-zA-Z0-9_-") ] [ _val = split_ident(_1, _pass) ];
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
           "ab_bcd_123",
           "ab-3_bcd_123 = 'something'",
           // failing:
           "ab_bcd_123_q = 'oops'",
           "ab_bcd_123_ = 'oops'",
           "_123 = 'oops'",
           "_",
           "q",
           ""
           }) 
    {
        NumberedIdent parsed;
        Demo::It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        bool ok = parse(f, l, Demo::rule, parsed);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "SUCCESS: ['" << parsed.first << "', " << parsed.second << "]\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed ('" << input << "')\n";
        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "  remaining input '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
SUCCESS: ['ab_bcd', 123]
SUCCESS: ['ab-3_bcd', 123]
  remaining input ' = 'something''
```

And then all the failing test cases (by design):

```
parse failed ('ab_bcd_123_q = 'oops'')
  remaining input 'ab_bcd_123_q = 'oops''
parse failed ('ab_bcd_123_ = 'oops'')
  remaining input 'ab_bcd_123_ = 'oops''
parse failed ('_123 = 'oops'')
  remaining input '_123 = 'oops''
parse failed ('_')
  remaining input '_'
parse failed ('q')
  remaining input 'q'
parse failed ('')
```